# User can View hiden details when editing Views

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I created 2 Views for Sharepoint list and manage the Views with user Groups

My Problem comes when User edit the View details that not in the View still visible (when you click and edit).

Is there a way  to hide these columns in edit mode or only allow the user to edit their own details?

Answer (score 0):

No, AFAIK there is nothing in SharePoint like column level permissions.. You will need to customize/develop this..

One approach can be to take away rights from user to edit views, and make custom Web Parts showing columns and update view from System Account programmatically (using [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx))

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.. 

can we create a  Permission Levels to manage this this .. ( Site Actions -> Site Permissions -> Permission Level)

Give Personal Permissions 

Add/Remove .. 

and Go to List Setting in site -> Advance Setting 

Change  Item Permission 

01 Read all Items 

02 Create and edit Items That was created by the user .

i change this but no luck with combination..

Appropriate if can help me on this ..